# How to get files from local Git repository in MacOs

Tags: git, macos, github, terminal, repository

I accidentally deleted two of my files. But yesterday i saved project in local repository by `git add .` than committed it, but i don't pushed it to the remote repository by some reasons. So how can i get my files back from local repository.  Thank you!
(i'm very new to git so thank you for any help)

Comment: but can i ask you about one more thing about git here?

Comment: Thank you @grg ! thats it